# Play the ToneGenerator cause ANR

Tags: android, audio

When click the dialerpad, play the ToneGenerator, but cause ANR。

The log:

```
01-02 04:02:48.209 392 2548 E audio_hw_primary: out_write: error -5, cannot write stream data: I/O error
01-02 04:02:48.209 392 2548 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xae38a800) usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback)

01-02 04:02:48.249 392 3038 E audio_hw_primary: out_write: error -5, cannot write stream data: I/O error
01-02 04:02:48.249 392 3038 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby: enter: stream (0xae3ed000) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)

01-02 04:02:48.772 423 1116 W AudioFlinger: write blocked for 10554 msecs, 50 delayed writes, thread 0xae883ec0
01-02 04:02:48.772 423 1116 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xae883ec0) throttle end: throttle time(19)

01-02 04:02:49.579 1767 1767 E ToneGenerator: — Stop timed out

01-02 04:02:52.639 1767 1767 E ToneGenerator: — Delayed start timed out, status -110
01-02 04:02:52.639 1767 1767 W ToneGenerator: Tone start failed!!!, time 8178550
```

You can check the code: [DialpadFragment.java--ToneGenerator](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/dialer/app/dialpad/DialpadFragment.java):

```
private void playTone(int tone, int durationMs) 
private void stopTone()
```

The ToneGenerator stop timed out cause the ANR. But what did ToneGenerator cause to stop timed out? How to analyze and fix this issue?

Comment: please provide code of ToneGenerator

Comment: I have edited the question to provider the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use and its work for me

```
 ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
 toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
```